# Angular 8 Checkbox Change Event Checked undefined

Tags: angular

Im trying to execute a function when a checkbox has been ticked/unticked
but wasnt able to get the checkbox.checked as it is showing as undefined.

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="eventCheck($event)" />
```

typescript:

```
eventCheck(event){
console.log(event.checked) <--- this is undefined
}
```

note: I was able to get the event object but im not sure which property to check if the checkbox has been checked or not.

Can you guys help me with this? thanks!

Comment: be carefull, if you use javaScript must be evet,target.checked, if use material angular is event.checked, if use (ngModelChange) $event is true or false.tip: use console.log(event) and see what are you receiving

Comment: thanks for the tip eliseo!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

it should be `event.target` try :

```
eventCheck(event){
    console.log(event.target.checked) <--- Check with this
}
```

**OR** Use it like :

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="eventCheck($event.target)" />
```

Comment: this works @vivek thank you!
ill tag this as accepted answer after 5mins

Comment: What is the type of that event parameter? Event interface does not have target.checked field.

Answer (score 3):

Here Is Solution...

> Chek.ts

```
testCheck(event){
       console.log(event.target.checked); <--- Return True/False Check/UnCheck
}
```

> Chek.html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" (change)="testCheck($event)" />
```